# Getting text from an EDIT control using WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

So basically I'm trying get text from text field, as I understand you get pointer from ***GetWindowText*** am I right? I couldn't place that text into long char so I had to use int and message box doesn't take ints so I had to transform into long char and then reverse pointer(&)? to display the text in a message box and that just printed me a bunch of nonsense

**case WM_CREATE:**

```
textbox1 = CreateWindow(L"EDIT",
            L"X0", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            50, 120, 50, 20,
            hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

**case WM_COMMAND:**

```
case 111:{          
TCHAR buff[1024];
int text = GetWindowText(textbox1, buff, 1024); 
TCHAR  textS = (TCHAR)text;
MessageBox(hwnd, &textS, &textS, MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);}
```

Comment: Remove `TCHAR  textS = (TCHAR)text;` and just use `buff`.

Comment: [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx): "If the function succeeds, the return value is the length, in characters, of the copied string, not including the terminating null character." Where did you see "you get pointer from GetWindowText"?

Comment: oh I used this function other way around as Richard said I just needed print "buff" which was unexpected for me, now everything makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `GetWindowText()` is the **length** of the copied text (not including the null terminator).  You are type-casting that value to a single `TCHAR` character, and then passing the memory address of that single character to `MessageBox()`.  This is just plain wrong.  `MessageBox()` expects a pointer to a null-terminated character string, so you should be passing your copied `TCHAR[]` buffer instead:

```
TCHAR buff[1024] = {0};
GetWindowText(textbox1, buff, 1024); 
MessageBox(hwnd, buff, TEXT("text"), MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
```

Alternatively, use a dynamically allocated buffer instead:

```
int len = GetWindowTextLength(textbox1) + 1;
TCHAR *buff = new TCHAR[len];
len = GetWindowText(textbox1, buff, len);
buff[len] = 0;
MessageBox(hwnd, buff, TEXT("text"), MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
delete[] buff;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the (wchar_t / TCHAR) buffer only:

```
int cTextLength; // text length
cTextLength = GetWindowTextLength(hWndEdit);// get text length
wchar_t * textS = new wchar_t[cTextLength + 1]; //dynamically allocate buffer
// get text from an edit and store it into a buffer variable
GetWindowText(hWndEdit, textS, cTextLength + 1);
// display the message
MessageBox(NULL, textS, textS, MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
delete[] textS; // free the allocated memory
```

Comment: `GetWindowTextLength()` returns an `int`, not a `size_t`. And this code will overflow the buffer if the text is larger than 1023 characters. If you are going to use `GetWindowTextLength()` then either dynamically allocate `textS` based on the actual length reported, or at least use `min()` to restrict the value of `cTextLength` to 1023 max.

Comment: Right you are Remy. I have updated the answer as per your instructions. I am not sure whether it should be `new wchar_t[cTextLength];` or `new wchar_t[cTextLength+1];`?

Comment: The length returned by `GetWindowTextLength()` does not include the null-terminator, but the size passed to `GetWindowText()` does, so allocating `cTextLength` characters and then passing `cTextLength+1` is wrong. Also don't forget the free the memory you allocate.